# What form of analysis for exploring associations of classifications?

Tags: correlation, clustering, categorical-data

I have survey data where participants classify a list of things as one of five categories e.g. {A,B,C,D,E}. For example:

```
  Participant · Thing · Classification  
+-------------+-------+----------------+
| Alice       | Apple | Category A     |
| Alice       | Bears | Category A     |
| Alice       | Trees | Category B     |
| Alice       | Rocks | Category C     |
| Bill        | Apple | Category D     |
| Bill        | Bears | Category A     |
| Bill        | Trees | Category B     |
| Bill        | Rocks | Category C     |
| Charlie     | Apple | Category D     |
| Charlie     | Bears | Category E     |
| Charlie     | Trees | -              |
| Charlie     | Rocks | Category B     |
+-------------+-------+----------------+
```

For my data, there would be typically 100–1,000 Participants, and 20–50 Things. Sometimes, a random participant might not classify a particular thing at all (eg. Charlie above, for "Trees").

What form of analysis could/should I use for exploring the associations in these classifications? E.g. can I discover that people that think Bears are Category B typically also think that Trees are category E? Can I discover that Apple and Trees are alike in some manner, while Bears are kinda but not quite similar, while Rocks are quite distinct? Or maybe that Bears, Trees, and Rocks are often similar while Apples are different?

(What are the keywords I should be searching on if looking for code on the main stackexchange site?)

Comment: Is the list of possible things (the middle column) fairly limited?

Comment: @Glen_b yes, there are usually 20–50 things, biased towards the lower range.

Comment: There are measures of association in contingency tables, but they tend to measure overall association (between things and classification) rather than identify specific components of it. Looking at some suitably standardized measure of deviation from independence could be a useful exploratory tool. However, that won't of itself identify similar things nor similar classifications (except in so far as their deviations would have similar patterns)

Comment: I (briefly) looked into Pearson's Correlation, but from what I understand of what I read that isn't the way to go either.

Comment: Pearson's correlation makes no sense since you don't have ordered categories. I was thinking about measures of nominal-nominal association

Comment: Could I take a piecemeal approach, and calculate the correlation between Apple[A] and Bear[A], then Apple[A] and Bear[B], and so on?

Comment: That would be a good question to put in your question.

Comment: I'll revise the question with this revised focus.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest you change the focus of the question, because I think there's other approaches than pairwise correlation, but it wouldn't hurt to ask about that approach.

Comment: Is Jaccard similarity and distance something I should look into for this?